# Latex connecting lines between nodes on Tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How can I connect 2 horizontal nodes on a tree? That is I want to connect z1 to z2. but the line should continue to the right of z2 and left of z1 to show continuity. Like wise for theta 1 and theta 2. [image: Tree image]

My current latex commands:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.2cm, 
                    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
                    level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}
                   ]
\centering
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw]

\node (Root) [black] {$z_{1}$}
    child {
    node {$\theta_{1}$} 
    child { node {$\varphi_{1}$} edge from parent node[left,draw=none]{} }
    child { node {$\varphi_{2}$} }
    child { node {$\varphi_{3}$} }
};
\hspace*{4cm}\node (Root) [black] {$z_{2}$}
child {
    node {$\theta_{2}$}
    child { node {$\varphi_{1}$} }
    child { node {$\varphi_{2}$} }
    child { node {$\varphi_{3}$} }
    child { node {$\varphi_{4}$} }
};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have some spacing and centering commands that won't work inside the tikz environment. Instead you can use `\node (Root) at (xcoord,ycoord) {...`

Answer (score 4):

I made some improvements to your code:

1. Using the `positioning` library for the `right=4cm of Root1` syntax.
2. Using `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`.
3. Renaming the `(Root)` nodes to `(Root1)` and `(Root2)` to connect them using `\draw`.

---

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{every node/.style = {circle,draw}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.2cm, 
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}
    ]
    \node (Root1) [black] {$z_{1}$}
    child {
        node {$\theta_{1}$} 
        child { node {$\varphi_{1}$} edge from parent node[left,draw=none]{} }
        child { node {$\varphi_{2}$} }
        child { node {$\varphi_{3}$} }
    };
    \node[right=4cm of Root1] (Root2) [black] {$z_{2}$}
    child {
        node {$\theta_{2}$}
        child { node {$\varphi_{1}$} }
        child { node {$\varphi_{2}$} }
        child { node {$\varphi_{3}$} }
        child { node {$\varphi_{4}$} }
    };
    \draw (Root1) -- (Root2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried to draw the line on other nodes but I get error can u please help

Comment: @user1965914 Of course, I can help. You could either post your specific problem as another question or we discuss it in the chat.

Comment: I need to draw a line from the left hand size of Z1 to the right hand side of Z2 as a arrow line showing the time flow. And same with theta 1. The line must start from the left most. I tried for a day now but i just couldn't make it work

Comment: @user1965914 Hm, I'm also stuck a little here, because `\draw (Root1) to[out=180,in=0,bend left] (Root2);` doesn't work as expected.